# Bootstrap 4 carousel with Angular 6 - Ol links in ngFor

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I want to create carousel with Bootstrap 4 and Angular 6, everything is working good but I have one issue. I want to add Indicators dynamically with *ngFor loop, my problem is that attribute `data-slide-to` must have numbers equals to numbers of photos. I'm adding this with loop so i want to pass there `i` from index value. Links are not working and in my browser i see in each photo `data-slide-to = "i"`

How can i bind there data to this attribute ??

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" *ngFor="let li of sliderImages; let i = index" data-slide-to="i" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}"></li>

      </ol>
```

I have tried `[data-slide-to]` and `data-slide-to = "{{i}}"` but these throws me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're looking for one of the following syntax:

```
[attr.data-slide-to]="i"
```

or

```
attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}"
```

Comment: Yeah :) I forgot about it, Thank you very much!

Comment: @yurzul could you pls help me on  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461294/bootstrap-carousel-indicator-active-color-change-not-working-inside-ngfor-ang)